# Is it possible for an admin alert when stock is low

Tags: expresso-store, stock

I want to enable an alert to notify me when stock falls below a certain number. Is this possible in any way?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box currently that would allow you to do this. Having said that you could use ObjectivHTML's brilliant Post Master add-on to set up a notification when stock is low